# Where to you monkey patch the Django user model?

Tags: python, django, monkeypatching

I want to monkey patch the user model from Django.

My code:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.add_to_class('secret_question', models.CharField(max_length="100"))
User.add_to_class('answer', models.CharField(max_length="100"))
User.add_to_class('DOB', models.DateField())
```

Where do I place this code so that `python manage.py syncdb` will create the correct table?

I tried the main directory `models.py`, I tried an app's directory's `models.py` (these two didn't produce the correct table), and I tried placing it in the `settings.py` of the project (error, couldn't run).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please take a look at [Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user) section of the authentication documentation. It suggests a cleaner way to add additional information to a User object.

> If you'd like to store additional information related to your users, Django provides a method to specify a site-specific related model -- termed a "user profile" -- for this purpose.

Comment: from what I read, user profiling is simply creating two tables with a one to one relationship?  If this is the case, wouldn't certain queries such like select * require an additional join and thus decrease efficiency?

Comment: I don't know the scope of your project, but I'd worry about maintainability first and about performance later. Also, you ask for the `profile` explicitly by using the provided `get_profile` method on the User object - just then the additional table is queried, without a `join` I suppose.

Comment: I'll certainly consider using the user profile technique, however, do you know how to do it with add_to_class?

Comment: I probably do, but I won't go into detail here - it's not the right use case for monkey patching - sorry ;)

Comment: lol if you won't answer that then please answer this: so let's say I do really care about performance, but still want to use the user auth system and django, how do I do it?  Assuming that I don't use the profiling technique.

Comment: @Derek, I just looked up the code for `get_profile` - except for the first time (where it populates a cache) - it boils down to 1 (in words: one) statement: `return self._profile_cache` - I can't see how you would beat that :)

Comment: hehe u win lol, just to know for sure, you can't subclass the User Model as of the current 1.3 version right?

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to monkey patch user model, there already exists an app for this.
[Django-primate](https://github.com/aino/django-primate)

> A modular django user.
>
> This Django application monkey patches
>   django in order to have a custom User
>   model that plugs into the
>   django.contrib.auth application.